# How do I Enable Add-In's in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I look for my favorite Add-In in the Trust Center of Outlook 2007, I see it, but it is disabled, I do not see an option to enable it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Help>Disabled Item's and select your item to enable it.

[image]